# I can not debug ASP.NET in Monodevelop - Missing extension

Tags: mono, monodevelop, external-dependencies, flatpack

Come on, I'll try to be objective.
I installed the monodevelop via flatpack (I've tried the Stable versions 6.3 and Alpha Preview 8 - 7.0)

I have 3 problems, but only 1 of them is serious, I'll start with the serious one, which I want to solve:

1. **I can not debug ASP.NET.**
   When opening the IDE I get the following error message: ***The Following extensions could not be started - Full Path: MonoDevelop.Ide***. I click on yes and everything works fine, but I can not debug asp.net
   [image: Monodevelop startup error]
   *Attention: It is not the same thing of this question: 
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/770299/monodevelop-on-xubuntu-missing-asp-net
   I also had this problem 1 year ago and solved, now it's different*
2. When I run a WEB application, **the Browser does not open** and I get an error message. But if I manually open and type the URL, everything works.[image: Running ASP.NET Error - Debug or Not]
3. When **running a console application, I get an error**, this I managed to work around following this response: [monodevelop cannot execute project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159145/monodevelop-cannot-execute-project)

---

### **I just need to troubleshoot the debugging issue for ASP.NET**

This is it. Need help.

***ps:***

I have already uninstalled and installed again and nothing, the same error, until I downloaded to previous versions, already tried until version 5.10.0.871-0xamarin2

Comment: System: Lubuntu 17.04 (with xubuntu and mate environment installed later)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with the Flatpak version about 2 mins after I installed it!!

I have built a v6.3 clone source from Github using the guide at,
https://kvssoft.wordpress.com/2016/12/13/building-monodevelop-on-ubuntu/
and it works for ASP.NET

Comment: when i try "./configure --profile=stable --enable-release
", i get this error : error: Can't find "fsharpc" in your PATH

Comment: work, but, I had to do this: i edit Makefile.am and remove "external/fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/FSharpBinding.addin.xml \" line

so , i remove fsharpbinding (rm -r external/fsharpbinding)

then, i remove this lines from Configure

if test "x$FSHARPC" = "x" ; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Can't find "fsharpc" in your PATH])
fi

and remove from Main.sln

every FSharp.fsproj and nested under project

After this

Configure
Make 
and Run... works

But !!!!

The Same Error related in my question !!!!!!  The same....

Comment: Maybe you don't need to rebuild from source, as there is an alternative installer, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1